# Чтение файлов из разных потоков

Tags: java, многопоточность, файлы

Есть [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/), [Chrome Driver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/). Есть прокси через которое я подключаюсь.

Прокси требует авторизацию. хром не поддерживает `http auth alert`, поэтому пришлось сделать расширение для него которое проводит авторизацию.

Оно состоит из двух файлов: `manifest.json` и `background.js`.
Прокси у меня много - я использую выборочно, случайно. Но что бы это сделать мне нужно считать содержимое `background.js` файла и подставить данные в нужные мне места. Я считываю содержимое обоих файлов, подставляю данные и запихиваю всё в `zip` - так нужно для хрома. Всё это конечно же делается в разных потоках.

Какова вероятность ошибки при считывании?

Comment: Если в процессе считывания файл(ы) не изменяются, то читать можно любым количеством потоков.

Comment: @SergeiK Спасибо.

Comment: сделайте синхронизацию для считывания, что бы несколько раз не считывать одно и тоже, и храните файлик в памяти

Comment: вообще задача не очень ясна, но вы уверены что есть смысл из разных потоков считывать файлы? скорее всего выгоднее будет считывать/записывать их последовательно в одном потоке, потому что если писать на hdd, то операции доступа к случайным участкам памяти будут требовать значительно больше времени, чем доступ к одному участку(из-за того, что диску приходится перемещать головку). в таком случае расходы на запись могут быть больше выигрыша от многопоточности

Comment: @НикитаГордеев в JavaEE считывать в одном потоке не получится.

Comment: @DaysLikeThis тобишь вы предлагаете один раз его считать и хранить? я работаю с Java EE - веб сервер.

Comment: и что религия Java EE сервера не позволяет написать отдельный класс синглтон для работы с файликом, обеспечить синхронизацию и кеширование?

Comment: @DaysLikeThis позволяет. В принципею

Comment: @Tsyklop вы имеете в виду, что разные потоки - это разные соединения(клиенты)? тогда, вероятно, будет выгодно сделать кеширующий синглтон, в котором будут эти файлы, но это лишь если клиентов будет достаточно много(допустим, больше пары сотен запросов в секунду к этим файлам), если же запросов будет сравнительно немного - можно считывать каждый раз. Но это только если нужно считывать, если надо еще и изменять эти файлы - синглтон делать придется и придется синхронизировать потоки при записи, и, возможно, как-то блокировать этот файл на время записи

Comment: и да, если просто считывать не изменяя файл - ошибку получить невозможно(но не в случае, когда вы пишете считанные данные разными потоками в одну переменную без синхронизации - так делать не стоит)

Comment: @НикитаГордеев уже сделал сингл тон который считывает и хранит в себе контент при запуске сервака.